# Cronjob but for jQuery/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter, cron

I'm trying to develop a web application that mainly uses PHP but i'm using jQuery/Javascript to grab people's Tweets from their URL: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?

The thing is want to run a PHP cron job to grab latest tweets from people who have signed up for my application. But i dont know how to do this with javascript?

Is this possible?

EDIT:

This is the javascript code, can i do this in PHP so i can use a Cron Job?

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

        var url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $("#twitter-posts").append("<p>" + item.text.linkify() + " <span class='created_at'>" + relative_time(item.created_at) + " via " + item.source + "</span></p>");
            });
        });
    });

    String.prototype.linkify = function() {
        return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
    return m.link(m);
  });
 }; 
  function relative_time(time_value) {
      var values = time_value.split(" ");
      time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
      var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
      delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

      var r = '';
      if (delta < 60) {
        r = 'a minute ago';
      } else if(delta < 120) {
        r = 'couple of minutes ago';
      } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
      } else if(delta < (90*60)) {
        r = 'an hour ago';
      } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
        r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
      } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
        r = '1 day ago';
      } else {
        r = (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
      }

      return r;
}
function twitter_callback ()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I agree, jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well.

Comment: Why the vote down?? Ridiculous

Comment: Probably because you are using the wrong tool for the job (cron is server-side, javascript is client-side) and someone felt that somehow that made this a bad question. It's not, and I've counter-voted.

Comment: thanks, the thing is, i understand the differences, but i'm asking CAN it be done

Comment: No, you can't run browser-side code without the browser being open. `#twitter-posts` doesn't even exist without the browser...

Comment: **Where** is it that you want (or expect) the JavaScript/jQuery code to run?  Surely there are PHP facilities that allow you to fetch content from a URL.

Comment: @ceejayoz JavaScript can be run anywhere there's a JavaScript interpreter. It does not have to be inside a browser. Now, jQuery code, well, it doesn't *have* to be in a browser, but there's not much point to using a DOM manipulation toolkit if there's no DOM around :-)

Comment: I want to run the code on a cron job, grab tweets, store in database...can that be done with PHP?

Comment: You want the JavaScript code to run on your server, in other words. What exactly is the appeal of doing it in JavaScript?  That's going to be a pain to set up, manage, and maintain on your server, because now you've got two separate programming environments to worry about. I wouldn't be surprised to learn about a PHP modification that provides access to a JavaScript interpreter, but for something this simple it doesn't seem worthwhile at all.

Comment: @Pointy Sure, there's stuff like Node.js, but this jQuery code assumes the existence of DOM objects like `#twitter-posts`.

Comment: Yes @ceejayoz you're definitely right about that - it seems that our OP has found some code to use but it just happens to be in the wrong language :-)  I don't know PHP but this can't really be that hard - fetching some JSON and parsing it should be a common thing.

Comment: FYI I've edited my answer to give you a headstart on the PHP-side implementation, which won't be very tough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to re-implement your functionality in PHP:

```
<?    
$url = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/joebloggs.json?count=1&callback=?";
$responseJsonString = file_get_contents($url);
$responseArray = json_decode($responseJsonString, $array=true);

// uncomment this to see what's in the response array:
// print_r($responseArray);
// Now, you can do as you like with $responseArray
```

And then execute the PHP script via crontab.

Comment: As in the code i have for getting latest tweets is in Javascript, so i need it to run as a cron job (i realise cron's are for PHP but i need to implement the same functionality for the javascript code)

Answer (score 4):

The javascript method setInterval allows you to pass a method and a number of milliseconds. The method you provide will be executed every number of milliseconds you provided. So if you wanted to grab the latest tweets every 30 seconds, you would call something like this:

```
setInterval(updateTweets,30000);
```

This would call the method updateTweets every thirty seconds, where you could use ajax to load up the latest tweets.

For more information on setInterval, you can check out: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: hi Dustin, i understand about setInterval but i need the code to run regardless if a browser is open (like a PHP cron job) could i call some jQuery with a Cron Job?

Comment: Why would you want browser-side code to run when the browser isn't open?

Comment: Then the simple answer is no, unfortunately. jQuery is, as @ceejayoz mentioned, browser-side code, meaning it runs in the browser only. No browser, no browser-side code.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is i need to get the job done with PHP, but the code above is jQuery and i dont know if PHP can achieve the same results