# Javascript alternative to CronJob

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cron

Is there any javascript alternative to Cronjob?

The thing is, my boss doesn't want to use CronJob anymore for daily executions and told me that if we can do it with javascript instead of CronJob.

I wrote a php+javascript code. It basically collects the daily tasks data (which .php file to execute, what is the time interval etc.) from the database and put them in an object.

Then,

```
<script>
    function mainFunc(){    
        for(var i=0; i<sizeOfJobs(); i++){ //traverse in the object
            currentDate = new Date();
            //if any of the jobs execution time has come, execute it           
            if(jobs[i]['next_run'] <= currentDate){ 
                $.ajax({
                    url: jobs[i]['file_location'] ,
                    async: false, //this is another question, look below please
                    success: function(data){
                        //after the finish, set next_run and last_run                   
                        currentDate = new Date();                    
                        jobs[i]['last_run'] = currentDate;
                        var nextRun = new Date();
                        nextRun.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + (jobs[i]['interval'] * 60 * 1000));  
                        jobs[i]['next_run'] = nextRun;                        

                    }
                });            
            }                    
        }
        //repeat

        //currently 10 sec but it will increase according to jobs max runtime        
        setTimeout(mainFunc,10000); 
    } 


        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(mainFunc,10000);        
        })
</script>
```

So, I use this code. It works fine for basic jobs but there will be a huge jobs which will take 10+ min to finish (like deleting and refilling a db table with thousands of rows)

- Is it safe?
- Should I set "async" value to false or not?
- I'm aware of the situation that there could be jobs which has to execute at the same time and if I set async false, every job needs to wait to finish the previous job etc. so I need to set setTimeout value to total max runtime of all the jobs.
- If I set it true what it could be happen? My fear is, if a job can't finish before setTimeout interval, it's next_run will not be set and it will automatically re-execute. so should I set next_run value before the ajax call?

Back to the main topic, should I need to do all of this? Is there a better solution or library? (I googled but couldn't find anything useful.)

Thank you

Comment: setInterval(fun_here,30000); ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695629/cron-job-but-for-jquery-javascript

Comment: yeah i saw it before post this question but unfortunately it does not a solution to my problem.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this is feasible... but I'd be even more interested to know why your boss is seemingly so averse to using cron: a reliable, readily-available job scheduler. especially since you mentioned you'll be performing server-side operations like db truncates/inserts etc. seems like he's weaving a world of pain for you :o

Comment: "my boss doesn't want to use CronJob anymore for daily executions" - what a bad idea

Comment: Maybe we can offer a solution if you share the ill-fated reason behind this decision.

Comment: Sounds like someone should fire your boss. Emulating cronjobs e.g. via AJAX request is often called "poor man's cron" and used as a workaround on shared hosting where you do not have real cronjobs. Using them if you can use real cronjobs is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in my professional opinion, your boss is crazy :)

Having said that, here's some changes you can make to address your fears:

1. Create an array of `job_execution_slots` with the same length as your `jobs` array; initialize to `null` values.
2. Before you do `$.ajax()` you check whether the `job_execution_slots[i]` is "taken" (not `null`).
3. When the slot is empty, you do `job_execution_slots[i] = $.ajax({...})` and make sure it's set to `async: true`; keeping the reference also allows you to "kill" a job by stopping the AJAX request.
4. In your AJAX completion handler you do `job_execution_slots[i] = null;`

This basically serializes the execution per job.

Let me know if this makes sense to you; I can supply further details upon demand :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster it also depends on the `$.ajax` global settings, so I always ask to make sure :) btw, good luck with the elections, you're doing very well!

Comment: actually it's being used for 3 days :D I've run this code on the server machine (with async: false . it's kinda slow the code down but safer) works good so far. I'm sure it will blow up when the time has come, but I've warned the company. I can't believe I wrote down a javascript task scheduler anyway. I'm not sure it's an accomplishment or failure :D Thanks for your advices though, it is really a nice idea. Maybe I will apply this when the maintenance time has come.