# How to automatically call javascript function every hour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a javascript function that gets a JSON object from a URL and I want to refresh the JSON object every hour with up to date data.

I am assuming the way to do this is to recall the javascript function that gets the JSON object from a URL every hour.

However I do not know how to set a function to automatically rerun every hour, could someone explain how this is done?

Thank you

Comment: client side? you can use `setInterval`, this requires your page to be open and stay opened all the time though..

Comment: read up on setinterval - but who has a web page open for an hour?

Comment: you could probably use a cron job look at this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695629/cronjob-but-for-jquery-javascript

Comment: Presuming the AJAX contacts a server side language (PHP or whatever), store the time of the last refresh in a database. Then, check that an hour has passed against the stored last update time before requesting the JSON object.

Comment: Could everyone writing an answer at least get the number of bloody milliseconds right? Sheesh.

Comment: Its for a analaytics dashboard that will probably get left on all the time on a tv screen. :)

Comment: is setInterval the correct way to go then? I'm getting confused by all the downvotes!

Comment: sad that downvoters don't give the reasons!! sigh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function doSomething()
{
    alert('Test');
}


setInterval(doSomething, 60*60*1000);
```

Comment: The time is in milliseconds

Comment: setInterval takes ms not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-call your function with setting an interval:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function getJSONObjectFromURL(){
      // do stuff
   }
   //set interval in milliseconds and call function again
   //1h = 60m = 3600s = 3600000ms
   var timeoutID = window.setInterval(getJSONObjectFromURL, 3600000);
</script>
```

Comment: Missed the 4 exact same answers below then, did we?

Comment: Yeah u are right, they were not there, when i started typing my answer. For me that is no reason to vote something down! I am sorry, but i didn't see it while giving my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3600000);
```

Where 3600000 is the time interval in miliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

Go with `setInterval` as shown below :-

**Syntax**

```
setInterval(function,milliseconds,lang)
```

**Parameter Values**

```
Parameter         Description

function         Required. The function that will be executed 
milliseconds     Required. The intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code 
lang             Optional. JScript | VBScript | JavaScript
```

**Return Value**

An integer with the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the clearInterval() method to cancel the timer.

**Example**

```
function test() 
{
     ////Your code
}
setInterval(function(){test()}, 60 * 60 *1000); //// 60 minutes = 3600 seconds = 3600000 miliseconds
```

**For more details** :-

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Using a string in a `setInterval` is an XSS issue.